# Send response to all clients except sender from io side

Tags: socket.io

I'm new to socket.io and I want to send a broadcast message to all except the sender. I already know the following code but I need it on io side not on socket side.

```
// sending to sender-client only
socket.emit('message', "this is a test");

// sending to all clients, include sender
io.emit('message', "this is a test");

// sending to all clients except sender
socket.broadcast.emit('message', "this is a test");

// sending to all clients in 'game' room(channel) except sender
socket.broadcast.to('game').emit('message', 'nice game');

// sending to all clients in 'game' room(channel), include sender
io.in('game').emit('message', 'cool game');

// sending to sender client, only if they are in 'game' room(channel)
socket.to('game').emit('message', 'enjoy the game');

// sending to all clients in namespace 'myNamespace', include sender
io.of('myNamespace').emit('message', 'gg');

// sending to individual socketid
socket.broadcast.to(socketid).emit('message', 'for your eyes only');
```

I am happy about any help!

Comment: Sry, I already found my mistake. I registered the events for each client so if any change was made every client fired the event.

Comment: After correcting it the broadcast works as expected. Thx